# 'ImportError: No module named ' error in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple Restful service in Python using Flask. I am a little confused with Python modules and how to use them. There have been many questions related tot this, however applying it in my case, doesn't help.

My project directory structure is as below:

```
algorithmservice
     |-api.py
     |-resources
           |- __init__.py
           |- optimization
                    |- __init__.py
                    |- instances.py
```

My `instances.py` looks like the following

```
from flask_restful import Resource

class Instance(Resource):
    def get(self):
        pass
    def post(self):
        pass
```

`api.py` is the following:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restful import Api, Resource
from resources.optimization.instances import *

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
```

When I run the command `python api.py`, I get the following error:

```
  File "api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from resources.optimization.instances import *
ImportError: No module named optimization.instances
```

i have tried a few other variations of the import statement, but none seem to work.

Comment: This look fine. I even went ahead and replicated the code and file structure per your specifications, and I am not able to reproduce.

Comment: In resource/init.py import optimization module

Comment: I tried `import optimization` and `from optimization import *` inside `resource/init.py`, it says `ImportError: No module named optimization`

Comment: @user3288346 I suggest re-creating a new structure based on what you posted as a question and try again. If it works, compare with the directory that does not work and you should find what you are doing wrong. Because, as mentioned, copying exactly what you put in your question, things are running fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did just what you told me and it seems to be working fine. I checked the code and it seems to be the same, so not sure what the problem is. I will go deeper and add an answer if I can find out the reason.